# Calling a function without entering its parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a JavaScript version of an old timey dice game named PIG. It involves rolling dice and keeping track of the sum of each roll. I need to be able to save each roll within a function and then be able to call said function to return the current roll score.

---

This is the method that takes the `amount` of the current roll and stores it into the variable total, subsequently returning the current `total` variable.

```
  function rollTotal(amount) {
  return amount;
  }
```

---

I first call the function and insert the score of the dice roll into the `amount` parameter...

```
var dieOne = 1;
var dieTwo = 2;
rollTotal(dieOne + dieTwo);
```

---

Then I call the function to return the current score like this...

```
rollTotal()
```

---

and am getting this...

```
undefined
```

---

Is there a way to set a default parameter to return the current score if a parameter is not entered when called?

Comment: `amount = amount == null ? defaultValue : amount`

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `rollTotal` doesn't update any variable. It's just an identity function, so `rollTotal()` returns `undefined` instead of `NaN`.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks for the heads up! That is indeed what I was getting, I just posted a typo. I corrected my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular way to do this is with an instance of a class.

That is:

```
function Dice() {
    var amount;

    this.rollTotal = function(_amount) {
        // if an argument is supplied, assign it to the internal amount
        if (typeof _amount !== "number") {
            amount = _amount;
        }
        return amount;
    };
}
```

Example usage:

```
var dice = new Dice();
dice.rollTotal(3);
console.log(dice.rollTotal());
```

Comment: Would the recent downvoter care to explain their reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function and don't supply a parameter, then the parameter is bound to `undefined` within the function. So you can do something like this:

```
var currentAmount = undefined; // or perhaps 0?
function rollTotal(amount) {
    if (typeof(amount) === 'undefined') {
        return currentAmount;
    } else {
        currentAmount = amount;
        return amount;
    }
}
```

You can do this more elegantly (and more safely) using a closure:

```
var rollTotal = (function() {
    var currentAmount = undefined;
    return function(amount) {
        if (typeof(amount) === 'undefined') {
            return currentAmount;
        } else {
            currentAmount = amount;
            return amount;
        }
    };
}());
```

You might also want to do a more robust test of the argument and treat any non-number as undefined. You can do this with the following test:

```
!isNaN(parseFloat(amount)) && isFinite(amount)
```

instead of testing specifically for `undefined`.

EDIT: As @Paul S. points out, the best test as to whether an argument was passed is `arguments.length === 0`.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain what's wrong here? Are you reading something in OP's question that I'm missing?

Comment: A different test you could do is `arguments.length === 0`, otherwise the IIFE version of this is basically what I would've written

Comment: @PaulS. - Yes, testing `arguments.length` is probably the right way to go.

Comment: @TedHopp  - Thanks! This will work just fine. I forgot about this option. You get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a function? The `=` operator works just fine.

```
// initial setup
var rollTotal;

// set in the middle of an expression
"You just rolled " + (rollTotal = dieOne + dieTwo) + "!";

// recalling later in an expression
"Last time you rolled " + rollTotal + ", what will you get this time?";
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can look at the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to check whether an argument was passed or not when the function was called. Here is how you can check if any argumemt was passed upon calling the function.

```
function rollTotal(amount){
  if(arguments.length === 0)
     return (a value when no arguments were passed);
  else return amount;
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking if `arguments[0]` exists instead of `amount`?  Also, the function that is outlined in the question doesn't roll the dice, it just saves a value.